# Mysql subquery alias with exists and union all

Tags: mysql, exists, union-all

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT '__HEADER__' as col1, 'HEADER MESSAGE' as col2 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT col1, col2,
       FROM table1) long_long_query
UNION ALL 
long_long_query
```

but seems that doesn't like the alias. I'd like to have the header only if results are present, obviously, and not to copy/paste the long long query twice. Is it possible?

Comment: You don't need an alias for a subquery used with `EXISTS` or `IN`

Comment: I need it cause it's the results, which are following the headers and are under the union all keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an alias to refer to the subquery used with `EXISTS`.

If you want to avoid writing the query twice, you can use a Common Table Expression in MySQL 8.x:

```
WITH long_long_query AS (
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM table1
)
SELECT SELECT '__HEADER__' as col1, 'HEADER MESSAGE' as col2 
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM long_long_query)
UNION
SELECT * FROM long_long_query;
```

Prior to 8.x you can define a view.

```
CREATE VIEW long_long_query AS
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1;

SELECT SELECT '__HEADER__' as col1, 'HEADER MESSAGE' as col2 
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM long_long_query)
UNION
SELECT * FROM long_long_query;
```

Comment: Yes, with clause is exactly what i was looking for, I thought about that and tried on AS 4.1 (preview) with the database inspector but didn't work. tried something like `WITH npr AS (SELECT 'whatever') SELECT * FROM npr` and no results. But in the app the complex query worked. Opened bug for android studio. Thanks.

Comment: You might have to tell AS what version of MySQL you're using, so it recognizes the features that were added in 8.0.

Comment: i think they were already aware of the issue, based on the comments on the bug i raised https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159575631 
Anyway thanks for your answer, was good to be sure the with clause was a viable solution.